# AWS RDS Postgres configuration for database disk size >1TB and almost 1B records?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, amazon-rds-aurora

For our applications, we opted for Amazon Aurora Serverless v2 (with PostgreSQL 13.8) because of its ability to automatically scale up and down. The ACU configurations are 16 - 128 (the highest it can go) and the cluster has 4 instances in total. I have also configured the `work_mem` to around 16 MB because I was getting `IO:BufFileRead` and `IO:BufFileWrite` wait events (and they went away).

The total disk size of the hosted databases amounts to almost 1 TB and the total records can go north of half a billion, actually closer to a billion.

During full operation, approximately 1000-2000 clients query the RDS via RDS Proxy (Amazon's pgBouncer variant). The total number of connections to the DB cluster is usually around 400-800.

I get `IO:DataFileRead` events quite often and I'm not sure why this is happening. In general, the database is not feeling "snappy" enough for some slightly beefed up queries that will return a few thousand records. We don't have much control over how 70% of the database is used because we're using a third-party Python package (which uses SQL Alchemy version 1.x). The remaining 30% is done by a fully optimized* FastAPI & SQL Alchemy v1.x combo. Query optimization is not a possibility (and, to my knowledge, not needed any more since we've done as much as could be done).

I've heard that the entire data should reside in RAM for the db server to be uber-fast. 1 TB RAM sounds like too much, though.

I'm starting to suspect the current config is just not enough...

What are my options within the AWS ecosystem for best performance?

EDIT: *"fully optimized" to the best of our capacity at the moment.

EDIT2: Some people have suggested I shared some example queries and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results that may help identify issues.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM agdc.dataset WHERE dataset_type_ref = 72;
```

will yield:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Gather  (cost=116978.63..22079013.48 rows=9098072 width=1467) (actual time=1399.420..121668.191 rows=8930699 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 4"
"  Workers Launched: 4"
"  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on dataset  (cost=115978.63..21168206.28 rows=2274518 width=1467) (actual time=1392.373..119077.067 rows=1786140 loops=5)"
"        Recheck Cond: (dataset_type_ref = 72)"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4855024"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=24653 lossy=515835"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_agdc_dataset_dataset_type_ref  (cost=0.00..113704.11 rows=9098072 width=0) (actual time=1345.052..1345.052 rows=8941399 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (dataset_type_ref = 72)"
"Planning Time: 4.276 ms"
"Execution Time: 122077.946 ms"
```

However,

```sql
SELECT * FROM agdc.dataset WHERE dataset_type_ref = 72;
```

...will time out (stuck at waiting for query to complete in pgAdmin for too long).

People have also pointed out that query optimization is usually more valuable than other optimizations at a lower level. While I appreciate this statement (and I absolutely agree), this is a situation where the queries are generated by a third party software which I have no control over. The best I can do is notify that team of developers if I have something valuable to share.

Comment: "*Query optimization is...not needed any more since we've done as much as could be done*" - Query tuning, index tuning, and database design re-evaluation are almost always the most effective way to improve performance problems *and* is a continuous process. Infrastructure tuning rarely makes the same impact. Sure, having enough Memory to cover the entire database is *nice* but a poorly tuned query will still perform terribly whether it's reading from Memory or modern disk with SSDs and NVMes being commonplace. Your best bet is troubleshooting the slow queries & asking about them specifically.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question above, optimizing the SQL statements, especially the most taxing ones, is unfortunately out of scope. Ultimately, it is the (virtual) hardware what will determine the maximum performance of any computing system, assuming a theorized “perfect” software optimization. I added a clarification regarding what I meant by "fully optimized".

Comment: "*Ultimately, it is the (virtual) hardware what will determine the maximum performance of any computing system, assuming a theorized “perfect” software optimization*"  - Yea but my point is the software side is almost never perfect, yet has the biggest variance in performance output relative to being tuned vs a much less variance in output from tuning infrastructure. In the realistic best case from tuning hardware, the gains may be minutes, but from tuning the software side the gains can be days or infinitely more, besides also requiring less time and money to effectively tune, usually.

Comment: '"fully optimized" to the best of our capacity at the moment.'  Well, maybe we could help you do better than your current best.  It is why you came here, isn't it?  But we can't help with just this info.  About the only answer we can give without more info is "sure, spray huge piles of money at it".

Comment: In the current setup, a simple SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE indexed_column = 50; takes over 1h to complete on one of my computers (or "gateway timeout" in pgAdmin in another) and it's supposed to return a little over 8 million rows. The table in question has around 200 million rows and that whole database is a little less than 500 GB. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Sotosoul Please add those details to your question. Also if you could add the table definition, index definition, and a sample query that would all be helpful. The best thing you could add though is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which basically tells you why things are slow. Without seeing it, I'd guess you're possibly getting an index scan instead of seek, which means the entire index (which could be the entire table) is being processed, to return you just the subset of rows of your `WHERE` clause. 1 hour to return 8 million rows is unreasonable and a sign of a software problem.

Comment: I have to second jjanes. If optimizing SQL statements is out of scope, you have excluded the most promising route. By throwing hardware at the problem, you can perhaps improve performance to a certain degree, but tuning a query can sometimes make it 100 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for updating your Post with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. If I read it correctly (I'm not a PostgreSQL expert but the knowledge is somewhat transferable) it does appear you're getting index scans as I suspected. Could you also please add the table definition for `agdc.dataset` and the definitions of all indexes defined on it. I understand you're saying this is a 3rd party query, but you'll honestly have a better chance at pointing out the issue to them to fix it, rather than trying to solve it with hardware (which would be like trying to squeeze water from a stone).